# Difference between "учился"/"учил", "убрался"/"убрал" pairs

Tags: грамматика

How do these meanings change when they are made reflexive? Does the implication change to doing something alone, somehow? Thank you.

Он учился русскому (всю свою жизнь).

Он учил русский (всю свою жизнь).

Он убрался в квартире за час.

Он убрал квартиру за час.

Answer (score 1):

The verb `убраться` in the meaning "to clean something" is marked in the dictionary as vernacular. So both the constructions are synonymous but only one of them could be accepted in a weel-edited newspaper, for example.

The verb `учить` is rather more literal than `учиться`. It's more concentrated in the process of learning: sitting at home and repeating the words or rules. `Учиться` in such conctructions rather means "he spent some time with the subject and got useful knowledge".

This difference is not so actual for languages (because learning languages is alsways hard), but could be more noticeable with math.

```
Он учил математику 6 лет
```

really means that he visited the lectures, learned rooles and read books, so made something visible. And he himself invested in this **process** really much.

```
Он учился математике 6 лет
```

means that he also learned math but the speaker is more concentrated on the **fact** that "he" was learning something. but theoretically maybe it was without books and he got all his knowledge "from the air".

Answer (score 0):

that might have been the connotation originally, but in the modern language i don't think it still applies, i'd say that now it indicates an intensive, persistent activity like `играться`, `дуться`, `плеваться`, `драться`

although

> Он учился русскому (всю свою жизнь)

isn't a normative phrase

`учиться` as a rule is combined with infinitives rather than nouns, as in the following phrase

> Он учился *говорить* по-русски (всю свою жизнь)

`обучаться`, a cognate of `учиться`, on the other hand can be used with nouns in Dative (or maybe it's Locative)

> Он обучался военному ремеслу

Comment: Your corrections are great! Thank you very much. I am most appreciative of your time and input.

Comment: "Мы все учились понемногу чему-нибудь и как-нибудь." Пушкин. А здесь все правильно?

Comment: for nearly 200 years ago i believe it is, plus you cannot compare poetry with prose, as due to metre constraints it tolerates irregularities, obviously `обучались` wouldn't have fitted in the metre, and there's an intervening word `понемногу` to which `учились` might actually relate first...

Answer (score 0):

- -ся is the present-day suffix which was developed from себя (=self), so just bear it in mind all the time when you see verbs with - ся:

мыть = to wash (to wash dishes)

мыться  = to wash oneself (to take a shower)

P.S.
Drop by my educational portal [expressrussian.com](http://expressrussian.com/), as well as my social media channels (you'll find on the site) to stay in touch with Russian daily.
Learning a language is fun, so subscribe and stay tuned!

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE. Please read this help article on [self-promotion](http://russian.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Comment: I have many questions that are very specific. I like _every_ aspect of languages including grammar mistakes that are consistently made, as well as all colloquialisms and even the grammar associated with profanity because all grammar has rules and all rules are observed or not with a consistency one way or the other. I'm afraid that I am going to annoy the moderators here by asking too many questions!

Comment: @Штефан Currently we have 2 questions per day on this site and we need [10 questions per day](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10848/russian-language) to stop being 'beta' site. So keep asking :)

Comment: I sit here staring at the clock waiting for the 40 minute time limit to pass to ask questions! LOL. I'm off work today and will sit here all day. I have documents with verbs of motion with almost 600 sentences that I am dying to ask about.